# How to Keep volume fixed in MediaPlayer

Tags: android

I am using `MediaPlayer` to play a sound and below is my code

```
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.sound);
    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.5f, 0.5f);
    mediaPlayer.start();
```

the `MediaPlayer` plays the sound in the given volume but the volume can be increased or decreased using the hardware key. I want to know if there is a way to keep the volume for my `mediaPlayer` fixed no matter what volume the user keeps using the hardware key

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFASIK Media Player does not provide any such Listener. You need to override key press events for checking that

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
            if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                //TODO
            }
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
            if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                //TODO
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
    }
```

MediaPlayer provide `isPlaying` boolean  to know either mediaPlayer is in use, you can use that in conjunction with KeyPress events.